# echo string into file fails when cp succeeds

Tags: bash, sudo, io-redirection, cp

```
OS: Ubunutu 14.04
```

In the /home/ubuntu directory, I created the following script:

```
echo >000-default.conf.test
sudo cp 000-default.conf.test /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.test
sudo echo 'this is a test'>> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.test
sudo cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.test
```

When I run the script, I get the following error message:

```
./test_f.sh: line 3: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.test: Permission denied
```

Any ideas why I am getting the error message when the copy operation is succeeding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

Redirecting output into files is done by the shell, not by `sudo`. So if the shell is running under unprivileged user, then `>>` is invoked earlier than privileges are acquired by `sudo`.

You can use the following approach:

```
echo >000-default.conf.test
sudo cp 000-default.conf.test /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.test
echo 'this is a test' | sudo tee -a /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.test >/dev/null
sudo cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.test
```

By the way, instead of

```
echo >000-default.conf.test
```

you can use

```
touch 000-default.conf.test
```

or even

```
>000-default.conf.test
```